# Powershell activedirectory web services

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am looking to have a webservice that makes a powershell call to add users to active directory. I have the PowerShell call but dont know how to make a webservice to issue the call. Below you will find the powershell script.

```
New-Item -Path <drive>:\RightsPolicyTemplate\<template_ID>\UserRight -Name <e-mail_address> [-FullControl] [-View] [-Edit] [-Save] [-Export] [-Print] [-Forward] [-Reply] [-ReplyAll] [-Extract] [-AllowMacros] [-ViewRightsData] [-EditRightsData] [-CustomRight <custom_right>,<custom_right>…]
```

I'm running windows 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a solution using PHP and HTML forms to call Powershell scripts to do the work. Please see my basic guide on getting started with this here: http://theboywonder.co.uk/2012/07/29/executing-powershell-using-php-and-iis/